# How to add class to kramdown-generated table of content?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, kramdown

I would like to add few Bootstrap classes to `<ul id="markdown-toc">`. How can I do it?

Input:

```
* ToC
{:toc}
```

Output:

```
<ul id="markdown-toc">
  <li><a href="#welcome" id="markdown-toc-welcome">Welcome</a></li>
  <li><a href="#header-1" id="markdown-toc-header-1">Header 1</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the class name you want to apply as an IAL:

```
* TOC
{:toc}
{: .this-is-my-class}
```

Then it will generate:

```
<ul class="this-is-my-class" id="markdown-toc">
  <li><a href="#" id="..">..</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is it possible to add a class to the link element?

Comment: @George Yes you can put the class inside the anchor tag `<a class="this-is-my-link-class" href="....">link</a>`